# Re-break a spline in ppform

Tags: matlab, spline

Suppose `p` is a Matlab [ppform](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/the-ppform.html) structure defining a piecewise polynomial function. The function is understood to be zero outside the interval `[min(p.breaks), max(p.breaks)]`.

Let `breaks` be another vector of (strictly increasing) nodes containing `p.breaks`. Is there a "neat" way to "rebreak" `p` as a piecewise polynomial with respect to `breaks` that as a function agrees with the original one?

This is useful to deal with piecewise polynomials defined using different sets of knots.

Comment: How are you creating `p`? Do you have the Curve Fitting toolbox (`ppmak`) or are you using `mkpp`?

Comment: I found [fnrfn](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnrfn.html) to do the job (in the curve fitting toolbox).

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you should answer (and even accept) your own question with more details so that others will benefit.

Comment: @horchler: it was your comment that turned out to be a sufficient hint